# Создание потока в функции C++

Tags: c++, многопоточность, функции

В нижеприведённом коде я пытаюсь создать поток в функции и выполнить в нём другую функцию.

```
void main()
{
  thread t1(A, String1, String2);
  t1.join();
}

void A(string String1, string String2)
{
  thread t[10];
  int score = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    t[i] = thread (B, String1, String2, &score);
  }
}

void B(string String1, string String2, int &score)
{
  ++score;
}
```

В результате получаю такую ошибку

*Error  C2672   'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found

Error   C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...) noexcept()'*

[image]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что сделано не правильно?

Comment: Вы используете идентификаторы `A` и `B` до того, как они были объявлены. А еще не джойните потоки в `A` и неправильно передаете параметр `&score` - он должен передаваться по ссылке, а не по указателю.

Comment: Плюс передача параметра по ссылке в поток без использования `std::ref`

Comment: @VTT, я написал так, чтобы сократить количество символов для удобства чтения, в настоящей реализации они объявлены

Comment: Псевдонимы функций объявить надо.

Comment: @VTT я попытался передать по ссылке, в результате та же ошибка

Comment: @Yami оформить ваш комментарий как ответ? Или просто удалить вопрос?

Comment: VTT прав, вам нужно убрать & перед score в создании потока.

Comment: @avalanche_of_misery: Вам помог мой комментарий?

Comment: @Yami да, помог! Я не изучил достаточно хорошо тему. В thread нельзя передавать ссылки без ref

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы передаете параметры по ссылке в поток без использования `std::ref`.

Вам стоит использовать `std::ref` о котором подробно можно прочитать здесь по [ссылке](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref).

Краткое описание:

> Шаблоны функций `ref` и `cref` являются вспомогательными функциями,
>   которые генерируют объект типа `std::reference_wrapper`, используя вывод
>   типа аргумента шаблона для определения аргумента шаблона результата.