# error C2672: "std::invoke": не найдена соответствующая перегруженная функция

Tags: c++, многопоточность, visual-c++

При передачи строки получаю ошибку "error C2672: "std::invoke" ". Подскажите как правильно передать стрингу в потоку?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

std::atomic_bool f = true;
std::atomic_int number_thread = 0;
int n{0};


void func_1(int n, std::string & mess)
{
    while (mess[n] != *mess.end())
    {
        if (f == false)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (number_thread == n)
        {
            std::cout << mess[n++]  << " " << number_thread << std::endl;
            number_thread++;
            if (number_thread == 4)
            {
                number_thread = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50));
        }
    }   
}

int main()
{
    int count_thread = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    std::cout << count_thread << std::endl;

    std::ifstream f1("test.obj");
    std::string mes{};
    f1 >> mes;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        std::thread thr(func_1, i, mes);

        thr.detach();
    }   
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    f = false;  
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Функция func_1 принимает 2-й аргумент (строку) по ссылке. А вы передаете в поток - по значению. Вероятно, правильнее исправить сигнатуру функции на `void func_1(int n, std::string mess)` или `void func_1(int n, const std::string & mess)`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Создание потока в функции C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/832533/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В [описании конструктора std::thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) написано:

> The arguments to the thread function are moved or copied by value. If a reference argument needs to be passed to the thread function, it has to be wrapped (e.g. with `std::ref` or `std::cref`).

Пишите `std::thread thr(func_1, i, std::ref(mes));`